# Why can't I run pip on Windows Terminal (Ubuntu profile)

Tags: python, windows-terminal

Installed Python 3.10 with [python-3.10.3-amd64.exe](https://www.python.org/downloads/)

Trying to start using python in my Windows environment, I get this in return when trying to execute `pip` in bash (Windows Terminal: Ubuntu profile)

```sh
$ bash > pip help

Command 'pip' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install python-pip
```

Can't `apt install package` either

```
$ bash > sudo apt install python-pip

[sudo] password for user:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-pip

$ bash > sudo apt install python3-pip

[sudo] password for user:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3-pip
```

It runs fine in `Powershell` tho.
[image]

Path environment variables (`User` and `System`) have been added for:

`C:\python310\Scripts`

`C:\python310\`

I've also tried making an alias for the `exe` in my bash profile (I've removed it)

`.bashrc`

```
alias pip='C:\\python310\\Scripts\\pip3.exe'
```

But it returns this:

```
$ bash > pip
C:\Python310\Scripts\pip3.exe: command not found
```

Seems to be an issue with `sudo apt update`, but when I try to update i get this

```
$ bash > sudo apt update
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

**How can I start using pip in Windows Terminal?**

Thank you.

Comment: How did you install Python on your machine?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt install python3-pip`?

Comment: But @Joe's question is very important: you have to make sure to install the pip package that goes with the python installation you did.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt update` first?

Comment: Thank you for reviewing everyone. I installed python 3.10 with python-3.10.3-amd64.exe and also tried `sudo apt install python3-pip`. I've added the result in the question.

Comment: @LordReptilia where was it downloaded from?

Comment: in the installer if you’re using the gui installer there should be a check box to include pip

Comment: If it works in powershell and you’d like to use a different profile open that terminal, and type powershell. You should now be able to use pip

Comment: With your latest `sudo apt update` errors, you seem to be having network issues in WSL.  Can you ping other hosts?  `ping stackoverflow.com`?

Comment: Right! I can't ping other hosts o: `ping: stackoverflow.com: Temporary failure in name resolution`

Comment: @LordReptilia Are you on a VPN?

Comment: I am on a VPN. Must be that :c

Comment: @LordReptilia Yes, see [this Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1398114/1165986) question and my answer there for some details and a likely solution for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely have at least two different issues going on.

First, with the `alias`, you are attempting to use the Windows Python and pip with WSL/Linux/Ubuntu.  You'll find multiple questions and answers here on Stack Overflow on why that isn't a good idea (even if you can get it to work).

Ubuntu already includes Python3 in WSL, and you should use that version if you are trying to develop in Ubuntu/WSL.

As for the `sudo apt install python-pip` failing, as noted it should be `python3-pip`.

As for the `sudo apt install python3-pip` failing, that's likely because you just installed WSL2/Ubuntu.  When installed most distributions under WSL, the repository caches do not come pre-populated, in order to save on bandwidth when installing.

It's *always* a good practice to `sudo apt update` before installing software, but it's *required* that you do it at least the first time on WSL/Ubuntu.

Try that, then `sudo apt install python3-pip`.

Comment: Thanks. Seems that I haven't run `sudo apt install`. I've attempted it but I'm getting `W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.` I've edited my question to include the full error message. 